# Set slack workspace token in config laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-blade, slack

I'm trying to set slack api workspace token from database.

slackMiddleware.php

```
  public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (session()->has('slack_token')){
        config(['services.slack.token' => session('slack_token')]);
    }
    else
    {
        $setting = SlackSetting::whereUserId(auth()->id())->first();
        if ($setting){
            session(['slack_token' => $setting->token]);

            config(['services.slack.token' => session('slack_token')]);
        }
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

when i'm trying to access index page api call returned data successfully. but when another page access. invalid auth error returned from slack api call.

master-layout.blade.php

```
@inject('channelRepo', "Modules\Slack\Repositories\SlackChannelRepo")

@php
   $channels = $channelRepo->fetchAll()->channels;
@endphp


@extends('layouts.admin')

   section('content')
   @parent

@include('slack::includes.workspace-selection')

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @include('slack::includes.side-bar-left', compact('channels'))
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        @include('slack::includes.header')
        @yield('slack-content')
    </div>
</div>
```

@stop

token received on every call from config. data return only on index page call.

SlackChannelRepo.php

```
public function fetchAll(array $params = [])
{
    //dd(config('services.slack.token'));
    $channels = $this->all();
    //dd($channels);
    return $channels;
}
```

index.blade.php

```
@extends('slack::layouts.slack-master')

@section('title', 'Slack')

@section('slack-content')

  <h1>Hi Slack</h1>

endsection

@push('stylesheet')

@endpush

@push('scripts')

@endpush
```